# Trouble loading project references during build within wpf user control library

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, enterprise-library

As an example of a build time assembly load issue, consider the following  class library code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        SqlDatabase database;
    }
}
```

And the following class code in a wpf user control library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace WpfControlLibrary1
{
    class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

The `WpfControlLibrary1` has a project reference to `ClassLibrary1`, but `using ClassLibrary1;` reference fails.  A different project type can load `ClassLibrary1` just fine, and if the Enterprise Library 5.0 `SqlDatabase` declaration is commented out, the wpf library can load `ClassLibrary1`.

Any ideas on what this issue is or how to track it down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause is that WpfControlLibrary1 is targeting .NET Client Profile, but one of the other libraries (e.g. Enterprise Library) is targeting the full profile. You can check the "Target framework" setting in the project properties dialog, in the "Application" tab.

You can see more details about the .NET Client Profile at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx, or about changing the target at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx.

Comment: +1 thanks Shane, getting tired and forgot to set the targeting library in the test example, which had the issue you mentioned.  Our real libraries have the targeting libraries set correctly, so back to the drawing board on isolating a simpler case.

Comment: Shane described the issue we were having while trying to narrow down our assembly loading issues with a test case.  I'll repost a new question once we narrow down the real issues we are having.